# Why nextjs static routing is not requesting HTML pages?

Tags: next.js, routes

I'm building a simple, html static pre-rendered website. When I test it using "serve" npm package I noticed something weird with the REST calls:

the browser seems to download just the first served html-page, and after that every new click to every internal link does not trigger any requests, just like a SPA.

but if I disable the javascript interpreter from browser settings, then I see that each click trigger its own html request to the server.

Given the fact that I checked my build folder to make sure that it's all pre-rendered html (and it is), and that I checked the source of the page to verify it's not client generated, how can this be?

Why nextjs use two diffrent way to mange routing for a simple static html website instead of the same one?

Comment: For me I don't even see the html files in the build folder. I see js files. Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: inside the path folders, if contents and paths are static (no SSR, no CSR)